# How to test thanos performance?

Tags: prometheus, thanos

How to test thanos performance?

I tested according to the official website documentation and found: connection closed before server preface received

cmd as follow:

```
./thanosbench stress  --workers=2 127.0.0.1:10902
```

port 10902 was query node

```
xxxx        quay.io/thanos/thanos:v0.21.1              "/bin/thanos query..."   3 days ago          Up 3 days           0.0.0.0:10902->10902/tcp                         observability-sandbox-thanos-querier-1
```

the log as:

```
level=info ts=2024-02-26T08:56:18.513530406Z caller=stress.go:118 msg="stress test encountered an error" err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection closed before server preface received"
level=error ts=2024-02-26T08:56:18.513602107Z caller=main.go:114 msg="running command failed" err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection closed before server preface received"
```

Is there a problem with my usage here? Has anyone used it? Ask for advice

----------------------------------------********UPDATE*******-----------------------------------------------

updeta the info:
After subsequent inspection, it was found that the port connected was http. After changing it to grpc port, it was found that the data was normal.